# EcmaScript6: strange behavior of console.log with WeakSet argument

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How the following can be explained:
if we comment first call to console.log, the `set.[[Entries]].length` will be `1`, if one is not commented `set.[[Entries]].length` = `0`;

Output: length = 0;

```
let mySet = new WeakSet(),
key = {};

mySet.add( key );           // add the object to the set

//console.log( mySet );     // uncommenting will change the [[Entries]].length
key = null;                 // delete key
console.log( mySet );       // [[Entries]].length: 0
```

Otput: length = 1

```
let mySet = new WeakSet(),
key = {};

mySet.add( key );           // add the object to the set

console.log( mySet );         // commenting will change the [[Entries]].length
key = null;                 // delete key
console.log( mySet );       // [[Entries]].length: 1
```

One more edition: if we add one more `console.log( mySet )` in the 2nd case (to the end of script). `[[Entries]].length` will be `0`.

One of commentors mentioned that it should be the garbage collector. But how it will behave in the real script? If I'll use one time calling the object (without second time) will it be deleted or not (after object will be setted to `null`)?

Comment: Why is this strange? You're _setting_ (waaay) a key to be an object reference. Then you;re removing that reference. I would personally like an explanation for this behaviour though.

Comment: @Ivar
I have changed the variable name (I have not learned setters yet), but that stranges are still occured.
I have changed the code a little bit, so anyone can just copy and paste it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, due to the second console.log call is still after assigning `key` as `null`. It should output the same result, but it doesn't. Review my explenation one more time.

Comment: Why should it be the same? You're setting `key` as a reference to `{}`.  In my mind, once you set `key` to `undefined` it gets removed from `mySet`.

Comment: It most likely has to do with when the garbage collector kicks in.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, sure. But you still see my code inattentively.
line_1: defining `mySet` variable. 
line_2: defining `key` and assigning an object.
line_3: adding the `key` to the `mySet`.
line_4: send `mySet` to console.
line_5: assiginig `key` as null.
line_6: here key is not an object. It should be deleted from `mySet` but it does not in the 2nd case. Why?

Comment: @Ivar. Yes, I think so. But how it will behave in the real script? If I'll use one time calling the object (without second time) will it be deleted or not?

Comment: I think you meant `[[Entries]]`, not `[[Entires]]`

Comment: @Bergi, sure, thank.

Comment: That's really odd. I have no clue why the additional `console.log` before the null assignment changes the output.

Comment: It might just be undefined behavior. Normally you can't access the length of the WeakSet. Using `.has()`  works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/mepqca32/

Comment: I never have length 0... Ah yes, when forcing GC it's empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't strange at all, it's just the standard behaviour of *weak* collections. [[Entries]] is an internal slot, with very much implementation-dependent behaviour, and might not even exist in the actual implementation but just be shown in the debugger.

Once you overwrite the `key` reference to the object, it can get garbage-collected and won't be held by the `mySet` either. The custom behaviour of `console.log` apparently creates another reference to the object (as you can still interact with it in the console) so it is not garbage-collected, and still shows up in the list.

Comment: but why the second call to `console.log` make the garbage collector to delete that reference?
Second `console.log` should make new reference in this case and object should continue to exist, isn't it?

Comment: @VadimCherepenichev Before the `key = null` statement, the object is strongly referenced and *must* be in the WeakSet` (where a `console.log` call finds it). After the statement, assuming the `key` variable was the last reference to the object, it can get garbage collected (but might not yet have been). When logging the set now, there's nothing that says the object would need to exist or be referenceable again. It does not "make a new reference" when there is no reference any more. (Of course all this is implementation-dependent, maybe `console.log` forces GC or not, *we should not care*).